# How to omit zeroes in a 1-D tensorflow tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I have a tensor like:

[    0.   235.     0.   213.  1006.     0.     0.     0.     0.    77.
     0.   234.]

How could one obtain the same vector without zeroes?

I want my result to be: [235. 213. 1006. 77. 234]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a way with pure tensorflow functions :

```
a = tf.Variable([0.235, 0.213, 1006.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 77, 0,234.0])
session = tf.Session()
initialiser_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(initialiser_op)
a_without_zeroes = tf.boolean_mask(a, tf.not_equal(a, 0))
```

`tf.py_func` is another solution to make it work with numpy but I'd expect drawbacks compared to a pure approach, mainly that you would not get the gradient computation among other things (no serialization in the graphdef, no distributed, no gpu?, probably slower performance?)

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely an answer to what I was looking. Is it guaranteed that when using pure tensorflow you will be able to do gradient computation?

Comment: I guess most mathematical operations will have a defined gradient, and if not the case, you can request it on github. But I would expect some operations where the gradient is not meaningful do not (patches extraction from an image for instance, or file loading...)